# How to rewrite where subquery condition in JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

There is a one-to-many relationship in my model, with master and detail entities. I need to construct persistence query so, that only those master rows are queried which have certain detail  rows.

I have composed persistence query like native SQL query, but it seems not optimal.

**Simplified master entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SED_JMS_REQUESTS")
public class JMSRequest{

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        targetEntity=JMSAction.class, mappedBy="ownerRequest")
private Set<JMSAction> sedJMSActions;

@Column(name = "REQUEST_ACTION")
@Min(1)
private Integer requestAction;    
...
}
```

**Simplified detail entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SED_JMS_ACTIONS")
public class JMSAction{
    @Id
    private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "REQUESTID")
private JMSRequest ownerRequest;

@Column(name = "REQUESTID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private Long requestId;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "REQUEST_ACTION")
private Integer requestAction;
...
}
```

**Appropriate native SQL query, which is working**

```
select * from SED_JMS_requests r
where (select nvl(sum(a.request_Action),0) from SED_JMS_ACTIONS a where a.requestid=r.id and a.status=1) = r.request_Action
```

**Constructed persistence query similar to above native SQL query**

```
select r From JMSRequest r where  ((select NVL(SUM(a.requestAction),0) from JMSAction a where a.requestId = r.id and a.status=1) != r.requestAction)
```

I have composed the persistence query, which is just analogue to native SQL query. It is working but as for me it is not optimal, as detail entity is already joined as @ManyToOne beeing fetched eagerly. 
So resulting persistence query contains detail entity twice, once as joined entity and once again in where condition.

Answer (score 1):

In JPQL you can JOIN related entities like this:

```
SELECT r FROM JMSRequest r
JOIN r.sedJMSActions a
WHERE a.status=1
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING SUM(a.requestAction)!=r.requestAction
```